# Question on OEIS A000085

Tags: nt.number-theory, sequences-and-series

The OEIS sequence [A000085](http://oeis.org/A000085) is defined by

$$ a_n \!=\! (n-1)a_{n-2} + a_{n-1} \;\text{with }\; a_0\!=\!1, a_1\!=\!1.$$

If $n$ of the form  $b^2-b+1, b \in \mathbb{N}, b > 2, \;\text{then: }\;$ $$ \left\lfloor \frac{a_n}{a_{n-1}} \right\rfloor > \left\lfloor \frac{a_{n-1}}{a_{n-2}} \right\rfloor$$

How to prove this?

Comment: Brackets $[\cdot]$ mean the greatest integer $\lfloor\cdot\rfloor$?

Comment: @LSpice The floor function.

Comment: Why are you sure that this is true?

Comment: @Mike The same comments that apply to that version of the question apply to this one. It's an interesting question, but there's absolutely no effort or even plausible argument shown.

Comment: This is true for $b=3,\dots,200$. It also seems that the inequality does not hold if $n\not\in\{b^2-b+1\colon b>2\}$.

Comment: This is equivalent to $\frac{a_{n-1}}{a_{n-2}}<b$.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your statement is (almost) proved in the paper [On solutions of $x^d=1$ in symmetric groups](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/canadian-journal-of-mathematics/article/on-solutions-of-xd-1-in-symmetric-groups/8F90642D9472FA7326164E54BE3BE57B). The $a_n$ in your post corresponds to $T_n$ in the paper, and the author defines $R_n = T_n/T_{n-1}$. The author then set out to prove $n-1 \leq R_n^2-R_n \leq n$*. The proof is on p.161 and can be modified to make the inequalities strict, simply by changing all $\leq$s into $<$ and all $\geq$s into $>$.

If $n=b^2-b+1$, then $b^2-b<R_n^2-R_n<b^2-b+1$, and $b^2-b-1<R_{n-1}^2-R_{n-1}<b^2-b$. Thus, $R_n>b$ and $R_{n-1}<b$, and your statement follows.

*This is paraphrased from p.161 of the paper; formula 2.8 in the paper is wrong, so I circumvented it.

Answer (score 4):

$\newcommand{\fl}[1]{\lfloor #1 \rfloor}\newcommand\N{\mathbb N}$User LeechLattice gave a complete answer to the original post.

This post is to complement that answer by confirming the empirical observation, made in my previous comment, that the inequality
$$ \left\lfloor \frac{a_n}{a_{n-1}} \right\rfloor > \left\lfloor \frac{a_{n-1}}{a_{n-2}} \right\rfloor \tag{1}$$
does not hold if $n\ge3$ and $n\notin\{b^2−b+1\colon b\ge3,b\in\N\}$. (Everywhere here, $n\in\{0,1,\dots\}$.)

The proof of this observation is based on the inequality
$$n-1<r_n^2-r_n<n \tag{2}$$
for $n\ge4$, used in the [LeechLattice's answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/412612/36721), where
$$r_n:=\frac{a_n}{a_{n-1}}.$$
It is enough to show that
$$\fl{r_n}=\fl{r_{n-1}} \tag{3}$$
if $n\ge3$ and $n\notin\{b^2−b+1\colon b\ge3,b\in\N\}$.
Note that $r_1=1$ and
$$r_n=1+\frac{n-1}{r_{n-1}} \tag{4}$$
for $n\ge2$.

It is straightforward to check that (3) holds for $n=3,4,5,6$, whereas $7=b^2−b+1$ for $b=3$. So, it remains to show that (3) holds if $b\ge3$, $b\in\N$, and $b^2−b+1<n<(b+1)^2−(b+1)+1$, that is, if $b\in\{3,4,\dots\}$ and
$$b^2−b+2\le n\le(b+1)^2−(b+1).$$

For such $n$ and $b$, by (2),
$$b^2−b<n-1<r_n^2-r_n<n\le(b+1)^2−(b+1) \tag{5}$$
and
$$b^2−b\le n-2<r_{n-1}^2-r_{n-1}<n-1<(b+1)^2−(b+1). \tag{6}$$
By (4), $r_n\ge1$ for all $n$. Also, $r^2-r$ is strictly increasing in $r\ge1$. So, (5) and (6) imply $b<r_n<b+1$ and $b<r_{n-1}<b+1$, whence $\fl{r_n}=b=\fl{r_{n-1}}$, so that (3) follows.

---

The proof of the crucial inequality (2) (given in the [paper cited by LeechLattice](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/canadian-journal-of-mathematics/article/on-solutions-of-xd-1-in-symmetric-groups/8F90642D9472FA7326164E54BE3BE57B)) is very simple but perhaps not easy to find. Indeed, (2) can be rewritten as
$$c_{n-1}<r_n<c_n, \tag{7}$$
where $c_n:=(1+\sqrt{4n+1})/2$, the positive root of the equation $c^2-c-n=0$, and, in turn, the bracketing (7) of $r_n$ is easily verified by induction on $n$ using the recurrence (4).

Answer (score 3):

Let $q_n$ be the quotient
$$q_n=\frac{a_n}{a_{n-1}}\ .$$
It may be useful to see the numerical values for the first terms of the $q$-sequence:
$$
\scriptsize
\begin{array}{|r|l||r|l||r|l||r|l||r|l|}
\hline
n & q(n) & n & q(n)  & n & q(n)  & n & q(n)  & n & q(n) 
\\\hline
1 &  1.0000000 & 41 &  6.8807053 & 81 &  9.4846377 & 121 & 11.4876422 & 161 & 13.1779753 \\\hline
2 & \color{blue}{ 2.0000000} & 42 & \color{blue}{ 6.9586914} & 82 &  9.5401259 & 122 & 11.5330579 & 162 & 13.2173548 \\\hline
3 & \color{red}{ 2.0000000} & 43 & \color{red}{ 7.0356175} & 83 &  9.5952744 & 123 & 11.5782873 & 163 & 13.2566128 \\\hline
4 &  2.5000000 & 44 &  7.1117592 & 84 &  9.6500913 & 124 & 11.6233328 & 164 & 13.2957503 \\\hline
5 &  2.6000000 & 45 &  7.1869362 & 85 &  9.7045808 & 125 & 11.6681966 & 165 & 13.3347684 \\\hline
6 & \color{blue}{ 2.9230769} & 46 &  7.2613608 & 86 &  9.7587503 & 126 & 11.7128808 & 166 & 13.3736682 \\\hline
7 & \color{red}{ 3.0526316} & 47 &  7.3349008 & 87 &  9.8126038 & 127 & 11.7573877 & 167 & 13.4124509 \\\hline
8 &  3.2931034 & 48 &  7.4077213 & 88 &  9.8661482 & 128 & 11.8017192 & 168 & 13.4511174 \\\hline
9 &  3.4293194 & 49 &  7.4797254 & 89 &  9.9193876 & 129 & 11.8458774 & 169 & 13.4896687 \\\hline
10 &  3.6244275 & 50 &  7.5510426 & 90 & \color{blue}{ 9.9723281} & 130 & 11.8898645 & 170 & 13.5281060 \\\hline
11 &  3.7590564 & 51 &  7.6216021 & 91 & \color{red}{10.0249738} & 131 & 11.9336822 & 171 & 13.5664302 \\\hline
12 & \color{blue}{ 3.9262662} & 52 &  7.6915065 & 92 & 10.0773304 & 132 & \color{blue}{11.9773327} & 172 & 13.6046423 \\\hline
13 & \color{red}{ 4.0563388} & 53 &  7.7607042 & 93 & 10.1294019 & 133 & \color{red}{12.0208177} & 173 & 13.6427433 \\\hline
14 &  4.2048605 & 54 &  7.8292772 & 94 & 10.1811936 & 134 & 12.0641392 & 174 & 13.6807341 \\\hline
15 &  4.3294803 & 55 &  7.8971884 & 95 & 10.2327092 & 135 & 12.1072989 & 175 & 13.7186157 \\\hline
16 &  4.4646191 & 56 & \color{blue}{ 7.9645039} & 96 & 10.2839538 & 136 & 12.1502987 & 176 & 13.7563891 \\\hline
17 &  4.5837324 & 57 & \color{red}{ 8.0311975} & 97 & 10.3349311 & 137 & 12.1931404 & 177 & 13.7940551 \\\hline
18 &  4.7087680 & 58 &  8.0973227 & 98 & 10.3856456 & 138 & 12.2358257 & 178 & 13.8316147 \\\hline
19 &  4.8226559 & 59 &  8.1628614 & 99 & 10.4361009 & 139 & 12.2783562 & 179 & 13.8690687 \\\hline
20 & \color{blue}{ 4.9397378} & 60 &  8.2278576 & 100 & 10.4863015 & 140 & 12.3207337 & 180 & 13.9064181 \\\hline
21 & \color{red}{ 5.0487979} & 61 &  8.2922992 & 101 & 10.5362507 & 141 & 12.3629597 & 181 & 13.9436637 \\\hline
22 &  5.1594060 & 62 &  8.3562227 & 102 & 10.5859526 & 142 & 12.4050360 & 182 & \color{blue}{13.9808064} \\\hline
23 &  5.2640568 & 63 &  8.4196203 & 103 & 10.6354106 & 143 & 12.4469640 & 183 & \color{red}{14.0178471} \\\hline
24 &  5.3692538 & 64 &  8.4825227 & 104 & 10.6846284 & 144 & 12.4887454 & 184 & 14.0547865 \\\hline
25 &  5.4698949 & 65 &  8.5449253 & 105 & 10.7336094 & 145 & 12.5303816 & 185 & 14.0916254 \\\hline
26 &  5.5704717 & 66 &  8.6068541 & 106 & 10.7823571 & 146 & 12.5718742 & 186 & 14.1283648 \\\hline
27 &  5.6674683 & 67 &  8.6683071 & 107 & 10.8308746 & 147 & 12.6132247 & 187 & 14.1650054 \\\hline
28 &  5.7640320 & 68 &  8.7293062 & 108 & 10.8791653 & 148 & 12.6544344 & 188 & 14.2015481 \\\hline
29 &  5.8577107 & 69 &  8.7898516 & 109 & 10.9272322 & 149 & 12.6955049 & 189 & 14.2379934 \\\hline
30 & \color{blue}{ 5.9507395} & 70 &  8.8499619 & 110 & \color{blue}{10.9750786} & 150 & 12.7364375 & 190 & 14.2743424 \\\hline
31 & \color{red}{ 6.0413902} & 71 &  8.9096386 & 111 & \color{red}{11.0227073} & 151 & 12.7772336 & 191 & 14.3105957 \\\hline
32 &  6.1312693 & 72 & \color{blue}{ 8.9688979} & 112 & 11.0701214 & 152 & 12.8178946 & 192 & 14.3467540 \\\hline
33 &  6.2191477 & 73 & \color{red}{ 9.0277422} & 113 & 11.1173236 & 153 & 12.8584218 & 193 & 14.3828182 \\\hline
34 &  6.3061933 & 74 &  9.0861857 & 114 & 11.1643169 & 154 & 12.8988164 & 194 & 14.4187889 \\\hline
35 &  6.3915252 & 75 &  9.1442315 & 115 & 11.2111039 & 155 & 12.9390799 & 195 & 14.4546668 \\\hline
36 &  6.4760013 & 76 &  9.2018921 & 116 & 11.2576875 & 156 & \color{blue}{12.9792134} & 196 & 14.4904528 \\\hline
37 &  6.5589859 & 77 &  9.2591710 & 117 & 11.3040700 & 157 & \color{red}{13.0192183} & 197 & 14.5261474 \\\hline
38 &  6.6411159 & 78 &  9.3160793 & 118 & 11.3502543 & 158 & 13.0590957 & 198 & 14.5617514 \\\hline
39 &  6.7219299 & 79 &  9.3726209 & 119 & 11.3962428 & 159 & 13.0988469 & 199 & 14.5972655 \\\hline
40 &  6.8019052 & 80 &  9.4288057 & 120 & 11.4420380 & 160 & 13.1384730 & 200 & 14.6326903 \\\hline
\end{array}
$$
The code producing the table is given at the end.

So (at least empirically so far) the sequence is increasing, has the asymptotic $O(\sqrt n)$, and jumps over the integers
as shown at the colored places:

- for $\color{blue}n$ in the "blue" list
  $\color{blue}{1\cdot 2}=2$,
  $\color{blue}{2\cdot 3}=6$,
  $\color{blue}{3\cdot 4}=12$,
  $\color{blue}{4\cdot 5}=20$ ... an entry which is $\le$ then respectively
  $2,3,4,5$ ... , and
- for $\color{red}n$ in the "red" list
  $\color{red}{1\cdot 2+1}=3$,
  $\color{red}{2\cdot 3+1}=7$,
  $\color{red}{3\cdot 4+1}=13$,
  $\color{red}{4\cdot 5+1}=21$ ... an entry which is $\ge$ then respectively
  $2,3,4,5$ ...

The OP question addresses only the "blue to red jumps".
It would be nice to have control on the asymptotic of the $q$-sequence that
reflects this observed behavior, so let us show in the sequel an *explicit* simple double inequality that separates the $q$-terms in pairwise disjoint intervals:
$$
\color{blue}
{
\tag{$\dagger$}
\underbrace{\sqrt{n+\sqrt {n-1}}}_{=A(n)}
\le 
q_n
\le
\underbrace{\sqrt{n+\sqrt{n-\frac 12}}}_{=B(n)}
\qquad\text{ for }n\ge 15\ .
}
$$
For the values for $n$ less than $15$ see the table.

---

From the relation $\dagger$ we have than immediately the claimed property. If $n=b^2-b+1\ge 15$ then
$$
\begin{aligned}
q_n &\ge A(n)=\sqrt{b^2-b+1+\sqrt{b^2-b}} > b\ ,\\
q_{n-1} &\le B(n-1)=\sqrt{b^2-b+\sqrt{b^2-b-\frac 12}} < b\ .
\end{aligned}
$$

---

Here are some words on the proof of $(\dagger)$.
(The main issue was finding the two functions $A$, $B$ in $O\left(\sqrt n +\frac 12 -\frac 1{8\sqrt n}\right)$ that allow an inductive proof.)

For $n=15$ the above inequality is satisfied, computer check.
Then we try to use inductively the relation
$$
q_{n+1}=
\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=
\frac{a_n+na_{n-1}}{a_n}=
1+\frac n{a_n/a_{n-1}}=
1+\frac n{q_n}\ ,
$$
so from the bounds for $q_n$ we would obtain the corresponding bounds for
$q_{n+1}$ if the
inequalities marked below with $(?)$ are true:
$$
A(n+1) 
\ \overset{(?)}\le\ 1+\frac n{B(n)}
\ \le\ 1+\frac n{q_n} 
\ \le\ 1+\frac n{A(n)}
\ \overset{(??)}\le
\ B(n+1) \ .
$$

---

For $(?)$ we equivalently rewrite step by step:
$$
\begin{aligned}
A(n+1) 
&\overset?\le
1 + \frac n{B(n)}
\ ,
\\
A(n+1)B(n)
&\overset?\le
n + B(n)
\ ,
\\
(n+1+\sqrt n)\left(n+\sqrt{n-\frac 12}\right)
&\overset?\le
n^2 + 2n\sqrt{n+\sqrt{n-\frac 12}} + n+\sqrt{n-\frac 12}
\ ,
\\
n\sqrt{n-\frac 12} + n\sqrt n + \sqrt{n\left(n-\frac 12\right)}
&\overset?\le
2n\sqrt{n+\sqrt{n-\frac 12}}
\ ,
\\
\sqrt{n\left(n-\frac 12\right)} + n + \sqrt{n-\frac 12}
&\overset?\le
2\sqrt{n\left(n+\sqrt{n-\frac 12}\right)}
\ ,
\\
\frac 12(n-1) +2n\sqrt{n\left(n-\frac 12\right)}
+ 2\sqrt n\left(n-\frac 12\right)
&\overset?\le
2n^2 + 2n\sqrt{n-\frac 12}
\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
And the last inequality can be shown,
estimate first
$$
2n^2
-
2n\sqrt{n\left(n-\frac 12\right)}
=
2n\cdot\frac 
{n^2 -n\left(n-\frac 12\right)}
{n+\sqrt{n\left(n-\frac 12\right)}}
\ge
2n\cdot\frac{\frac n2}{n+n}=\frac n2\ .
$$

---

For $(??)$ we equivalently rewrite step by step:
$$
\begin{aligned}
 1 + \frac n{A(n)} 
&\overset?\le
B(n+1)
\ ,
\\
n+A(n)
&\overset?\le
A(n)B(n+1)
\ ,
\\
n^2 + 2n\sqrt{n+\sqrt{n-1}} + n+\sqrt{n-1}
&\overset?\le
(n+\sqrt{n-1})\left(n+1+\sqrt{n+\frac 12}\right)
\ ,
\\
2n\sqrt{n+\sqrt{n-1}}
&\overset?\le
n\sqrt{n+\frac 12} + n\sqrt{n-1} + \sqrt{(n-1)\left(n+\frac 12\right)}
\ ,
\\
4n^2(n+\sqrt{n-1})
&\overset?\le
n^2\left(n+\frac 12\right) + n^2(n-1) + (n-1)\left(n+\frac 12\right)
\\
&\qquad
+2n^2\sqrt{(n-1)\left(n+\frac 12\right)}
+2n\left(n+\frac 12\right)\sqrt{n-1}
\\
&\qquad\qquad
+2n(n-1)\sqrt{n+\frac 12}
\ ,
\\
2n^3 + 2n^2\sqrt{n-1}
&\overset?\le
2n^2\sqrt{(n-1)\left(n+\frac 12\right)}
+
2n^2\sqrt{n+\frac 12}
+
\frac{n^2}2
\\
&\qquad
-
2n\sqrt{n+\frac 12}
+
n\sqrt{n-1}
-\frac{n+1}2
\ ,
\\
2n^2\cdot
\frac
{n^2 -(n-1)\left(n+\frac 12\right)}
{n + \sqrt{(n-1)\left(n+\frac 12\right)}}
-\frac{n^2}2
&\overset?\le
2n^2\cdot\frac{\left(n+\frac 12\right)-(n-1)}{\sqrt{n+\frac 12}+\sqrt{n-1}}
\\
&\qquad
+n\sqrt{n-1}-2n\sqrt{n+\frac 12}-\frac{n+1}2
\ ,
\\[3mm]
&\qquad\text{ and for the last relation, we estimate the LHS}
\\
2n^2\cdot
\frac
{n^2 -(n-1)\left(n+\frac 12\right)}
{n + \sqrt{(n-1)\left(n+\frac 12\right)}}
-\frac{n^2}2
&=
2n^2\left(\frac{\frac{n+1}2}{n+\sqrt{(n-1)\left(n+\frac 12\right)}}-\frac 14\right)
\\
&\le n^2\left(\frac{n+1}{n+\left(n-\frac 14\right)}-\frac 12\right)
=n^2\cdot\frac{2+\frac 14}{2\left(2n-\frac 14\right)}\in O(n)\ ,
\\
&\qquad\text{ and the first term on the RHS}
\\
2n^2\cdot\frac{\frac 32}{\sqrt{n+\frac 12}+\sqrt{n-1}}
&\ge
2n^2\cdot\frac{\frac 32}{2\sqrt{n-\frac 14}}
=\frac32\cdot\frac{n^2}{\sqrt{n-\frac 14}}\sim \frac 32n\sqrt n
\ ,
\end{aligned}
$$
and from the factor $\frac 32=1+\frac 12$
we need (only) the $1$ to compensate the other terms in $O(n\sqrt n)$ for "big values" of $n$.
(Computations can be done explicitly.)

---

Sage code producing the table:

```
a = [1, 1]
B_blue = [b^2 - b     for b in [2..99]]
B_red  = [b^2 - b + 1 for b in [2..99]]

for n in [2..1000]:
    a.append( a[-1] + (n-1)*a[-2] )

def q(n): return RR(a[n]/a[n - 1])
def q_color(n): 
    if n in B_red :    return r'\color{red}{%10.7f}' % q(n)
    if n in B_blue:    return r'\color{blue}{%10.7f}' % q(n)
    return '%10.7f' % q(n)

for k in [1..40]:
    print(' & '.join(['{} & {}'.format(j*40+k, q_color(j*40+k))
                      for j in [0..4]]), r'\\\hline')
```

---

Computer check of the relation $A(n) \le q_n\le B(n)$ for $n$ between $15$ and $1000$, here $A$ is `low` and $B$ is `up`:

```
def low(n): return sqrt(n + sqrt(n -  1 ))
def up (n): return sqrt(n + sqrt(n - 1/2))

prod([ int( bool(low(n) < a[n]/a[n-1]) and bool(a[n]/a[n-1] < up(n)) )
       for n in [15..1000] ])
```

And we get the $1$.

---

Computer check of the relation inductively shown above:
$$A(n+1) \le 1+\frac n{B(n)} \le q_{n+1}\le 1 +\frac n{A(n)} \le B(n+1)$$
for $n$ between $15$ and $999$.

```
ok = True
for n in [15..999]:
    qq = RR( a[n+1] / a[n])
    if ( bool( RR(low(n+1))     < 1 + n/RR(up(n))  ) and
         bool( 1 + n/RR(up(n) ) < qq               ) and
         bool(               qq < 1 + n/RR(low(n)) ) and
         bool( 1 + n/RR(low(n)) < up(n+1)          ) ):
        continue
    ok = False
    break

print(f'ok = {ok}')
```

and we get `ok = True`. (The flag remained as set initially.)

Comment: This answer was started during my after-x-mas holidays, at some point i saw the compact, accepted solution, so tried to improve and also get a short story. This is finally not simple enough, but the double inequality $(\dagger)$ is explicit and useful, and can be shown by simple means when having it. So i decided to submit, most of the typing work was already done...